# Avoiding global variables in Python

Tags: python, global-variables, conventions

I am aware that there are many posts regarding this subject, but I'm having some trouble grasping the concept. So I wrote a script and my companies' CTO scolded me for it, saying it's bad style since it uses an object instance which is a global var which is only created in the main part of the script. Therefore, the function won't work when imported from somewhere else where the instance isn't globally available.

Edit: here is the exact wording of the complaint:

*Function* `def updateValues(...)`*, e.g., uses an object instance which is a global var and only created in the main part of the script. This function will not work when imported from somewhere else where no such instance is available on a global scope. That's bad programming style.*

In my opinion, I pass the object instance to the function in the call, and, therefore, it doesn't actually use a global var. Questions back were not answered since he went on vacation. However, this does need to be deployed and I'm unsure how to proceed, so I turn to SO for help. Maybe someone here knows what he meant :).

This is a simplication of the script:

```
# This is called when the object instance is created
def getInitialValues(projectID,initial_time):
    timeseries_1,timeseries_2 = getData(projectID,initial_time)
    value_1,value_2 = makeInitialCalculations(timeseries_1,timeseries_2)
    return value_1,value_2

# This is called once a minute to update the values with the new data
def updateValues(Object,time):
    # actually I only grab the "new" data since the last call of course, out of simplicity I didn't put that in here :)
    timeseries_1,timeseries_2 = getData(Object.projectID,time)
    Object.value_1,Object.value_2 = makeUpdateCalculations(Object.value_1,Object.value_2,timeseries_1,timeseries_2)


class Functions():
    def __init__(self,projectID,initial_time):
        self.projectID=projectID
        self.value_1,self.value_2 = getInitialValues(projectID,initial_time)


'''MAIN PART OF SCRIPT'''

# creating the object instance
obj_instance = Functions(projectID,datetime.now())

# the loop that is deployed on the server
while True:
    sleep(60)
    updateValues(obj_instance,datetime.now())
    putNewValuesInDatabase(obj_instance)
```

Comment: Which function is your CTO worried about not working elsewhere?

Comment: This looks fine to me, but I would use the classic "if \__name\__ == '\__main\__':" at the bottom to run the main method (setting up obj_instance and running the while loop). Did you get any more specific feedback?

Comment: @Metareven If the OP did that, he wouldn't be able to import this from somewhere else and have the desired effect.

Comment: @RonaldAaronson I can't imagine that the intention of this script is to be imported and then automatically being run forever, or am I misunderstanding something here? Having a while True: loop in a file that is supposed to be imported is madness in my opinion

Comment: @Metareven The CTO's complaint, as I read it, was, "Therefore, the function won't work when imported from somewhere else where the instance isn't globally available." Re-read the question.

Comment: On a related note, the naming of a class called `Functions` and an instance called `Object` could be significantly improved!

Comment: @RonalAaronson Yes, but this isn't the original script, nor does that complaint make any sense in this case... However when reading the comments in the example here a bit more closely I wonder if the while True loop is code ran somewhere else and the file in question only contains the functions, the class and the object_instance, in which case I understand the complaint as the instance has to be instantiated by the ones using the functions and not be a global variable in the same file as the functions

Comment: @KathyRindhoops I edited the question to include the exact wording

Answer (score 1):

The program may work but I think it is not the best programming style, as some of the comments have suggested. By the way, I don't see a definition for `putNewValuesInDatabase`, so I don't know whether you just omitted it for brevity or it it would be in a file that does the importing of this file. No matter. Not to confuse the issue, but this is how I probably would have coded this (although I would have probably rolled `getInitialValues` into the `__init__` method because of its brevity):

```
class Functions():

    def __init__(self,
                 getData,
                 makeInitialCalculations,
                 makeUpdateCalculations,
                 putNewValuesInDatabase,
                 projectID):
        self.getData = getData
        self.makeInitialCalculations = makeInitialCalculations
        self.makeUpdateCalculations = makeUpdateCalculations
        self.putNewValuesInDatabase = putNewValuesInDatabase 
        self.projectID = projectID
        self.getInitialValues()
        self.start_updates()

    def getInitialValues(self):
        time = datetime.now()
        timeseries_1, timeseries_2 = self.getData(self.projectID, time)
        self.value_1, self.value_2 = self.makeInitialCalculations(timeseries_1, timeseries_2, time)

    def updateValues(self):
        time = datetime.now()
        timeseries_1, timeseries_2 = self.getData(self.projectID, time)
        self.value_1, self.value_2 = self.makeUpdateCalculations(self.value_1, self.value_2, timeseries_1,timeseries_2)

    def start_updates(self):
        while True:
            sleep(60)
            self.updateValues()
            self.putNewValuesInDatabase(self)
```

I have included `getInitialValues` and `updateValues` into your (not-so-well-named) class `Functions` and have simplified the interfaces. Note that now the constructor for this class must be passed the functions `getData`, `makeInitialCalculations`, `makeUpdatecalculations`  and `putNewValuesInDatabase` , which can be coming from the client code that *might* be in a different file that is importing this file. I would then expect the client code to be:

```
obj_instance = Functions(getData, makeInitialCalculations, makeUpdateCalculations, putNewValuesInDatabase, projectID)
```

You might wish instead not to have the constructor automatically call `start_updates` (or `getInitialValues` for that matter) and have the client code call those method(s) manually.